# should I check and remove outlier from dataset through multi round

Tags: standard-deviation, outliers, boxplot

I have a data set as: x1, x2, x3... x9 (non-normal distribution). I check it with box-plot and find one outlier as x9.  Normally I will stop then remove x9 and use the new data set. But when I check new data set x1...x8 with box-plot, I find one another outlier x8. I check new data set x1...x7 again, no outlier is detected.
My question is that: In this case, x8, x9 are outliers? or only x9 is outlier? For any dataset, should I do box-plot test again and again until no outlier is detected?

Comment: "Outliers" are a slippery concept. Why do you call x9 an "outlier"? Why do you remove it from the analysis? In R, run `set.seed(2); boxplot(rgamma(10,1))`: you get one "outlier", but this is a completely bona fide data point from this gamma distribution, and there is no reason at all to remove it. Outliers should be removed if they are *erroneous* and do not reflect the data generating process we are interested in.